# How to read multiple images from one cell in excel using image_loader in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, universal-image-loader

I'm using openpyxl to read an Excel file. When using `image_loader` to read images, I am able to read one image in a cell, but not multiple images in a single cell. How can I do this?